# Prove that the following map is a well defined symmetric bilinear map

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be an m dimensional manifold, and $f: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a real value smooth function and $p$ be a critical point of $f$.

Let $x_p, y_p$ be vectors in $T_pM$, define a smooth vector field locally at $p$, $X$, and $Y$ such that $X(p) = X_p$, $Y(p) = y_p$. Then define a map $f_{*,*}(x_p,y_p) = (X_p(Yf))$.

show that $f_{*,*}$ is well defined (independent of the choice of smooth vector field, and symmetric bilinear.
(Hint: Use symmetry to show that it is well defined)

This was an exam question, and I think I can show that it is well defined once I have shown that it is symmetric.

I'm not sure how to show that it is symmetric, or what does $p$ being a critical value of $f$ has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we show that it is symmetric, indeed, since $[X,Y]_p = X_p(Yf) - Y_p(Xf)$, and $[X,Y]p \in TpM$. we know that $[X,Y]_p f  = 0$ by assumption. Hence $X_p(Yf) = Y_p(Xf)$, therefore $f_{*,*}$ is symmetric.

Bilinearity is clear from the bilinearity of the Lie bracket.

Now we show that it is well defined,

By symmetry, suppose we have $X,X'$ and $Y,Y'$ such that $X_p = X'_p$, $Y_p = Y'_p$.

then we have $X_p(Yf) = X'_p(Yf) = Y_p(X'f) = Y'_p(X'f) = X'_p(Y'f)$.

Thus $f_{*,*}$ is well defined.